# Recover offscreen window

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, window

I had two screens connected, but now I disconnected one and took it away (it is not available any more). The problem is that I have DVB Viewer installed (DVBViewerTE from Technisat) and the last position of that window was in the other screen. Now I cannot move the window to the first screen - I cannot watch TV, I have only sound.

I tried everything, but the DVBViewerTE is some sort of freaked pre-XP custom made toolkit. No shortcuts work. No Alt-Space, no Win+keys, no Ctrl+Win+Keys, no Shift+Crtl+Win+Keys. Registry don't contain any "last window location" settings, nor the Program files folder has any config file with these.

The only solution is to reinstall, but I would like to know if it is indeed everything I could try.

Answer (score 1):

Does the program show up in the taskbar when the application is running?  If so, try right-clicking and selecting 'move', and then use the cursor keys to move it left or right onto the current monitor.  If it's a weird custom window this may not work, but I've fixed this type of problem this way before.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Right click on the taskbar offers the usual (Launch, Pin, Close), right clicking the live preview just closes the preview, no contextual menu is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GUI scripting tool to find the window, get a handle on it, and then move it to location x=0, y=0. This would place it in the top left corner of your desktop.

I use xdotool ([www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/‎](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/%E2%80%8E)) in Linux to do some fun automation things all the time.

For Windows, check out autoit (http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Answer (score 0):

A technique that often works is this:

- Right-click in the taskbar and choose "Show Desktop"
- Right-click on the problem program task and choose "Restore"
- Right-click on the some other program's task and choose "Restore"
- Right-click in the taskbar and choose "Cascade Windows"

This normally causes the window parameters to fit onto the current screen.